# Reading JSON-file without the SAS JSON libname engine

Tags: json, sas

I'm trying to getting data from a JSON-file to a table in SAS. Unfortunately I am not able to use the SAS JSON engine. 
So far I've got almost all the data to a table. I'm just missing a few values.

My JSON file looks like this:

```
  {  
  "eventsLimited":false,
  "events":[  
    {  
      "_id":"1",
      "userId":"1",
      "timestamp":"2017-05-07T21:37:39.037Z",
      "detailedEvents":[  
        {  
          "eventType":"taskChanged",
          "taskId":"111",
          "changedProperties":[  
            {  
              "property":"totalSecondsSpent",
              "oldValue":0,
              "newValue":3600
            },
            {  
              "property":"totalSecondsEstimate",
              "oldValue":0,
              "newValue":144000
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {  
      "_id":"2",
      "userId":"1",
      "timestamp":"2017-05-07T22:31:30.037Z",
      "detailedEvents":[  
        {  
          "eventType":"taskChanged",
          "taskId":"111",
          "changedProperties":[  
            {  
              "property":"totalSecondsSpent",
              "oldValue":3600,
              "newValue":5400
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My SAS code looks like this:

```
data iHave;
    infile 'C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\MyJSONFile.txt' recfm=n dlm='{}[],';
    input value : $200. @@;

    if value in: ('"count"' '"calls"') then
        delete;
run;

libname iTest 'C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop';

data iTest.iTemp;
    set iHave;
    length name v $ 100;

    if value =: '"_id"' then
        n+1;
    name=scan(value,2,'"','m');
    v=scan(value,-2,'"','m');
    drop value;
run;
```

This will give me an output that looks like this:

[image: Picture of my SAS output]

So far so good. For each object inside the array the counter (n) increments by one and the key and value is showed in a two different columns.

My problem is that I don't get what's inside the changedProperties array right. The two values for the 'oldValue' key and 'newValue' key is not showed in my output.
For example the first newValue should be 3600 in the 'v' column.

Does anybody know how i can fix my code so I will get my output right?
I think the problem is that numbers is not shown in parentheses and in my scan i search by values inside of parentheses.

/Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that you are telling the `scan` function that words are delimited by double quotes (`"`), with the `'m'` modifier specifying that consecutive delimiters as well as delimiters at the start and end of the string are to be accounted for and indicate empty words.

SO, while for your other key/value pairs (i.e., `"key":"value"`), it works because the first `scan` looks for the word that is between the first and second `"`, i.e. `key` and the second `scan` looks backwards for the word between the last and forelast `"`, i.e. value; for `oldValue` and `newValue` your value is not quoted which means that both `scan` functions find the same word, i.e the key.

You could fix that by indicating that the delimiter is the colon (`:`) and remove the quotes if there are any:

```
name=dequote(scan(value,1,':','m'));
v=dequote(scan(value,2,':','m'));
```

Comment: Perfect! Makes perfect sense. It's working now! You've solved my problem. Thank you very much

Comment: welcome. second argument of the scan functions were wrong though. fixed now

Comment: Oh, yeah. I didn't copy your code since you've explained it so well, that i wrote it myself.

Answer (score 0):

If your ultimate goal here is to get the data into a standard tabular format and the structure of your JSON isn't too much more complex than the snippet you've shared, it might be reasonable to hard-code a single, more complex data step to import it directly.

E.g.

```
data example;
infile cards dsd dlm='},' scanover;
input 
  @'_id":'  _id :8. 
  @'userId":'  userId :8. 
  @'timestamp":'  t_timestamp :$30. 
  @'eventType":'  eventType :$30.
  @'taskId":' taskId :8.
;
drop t_timestamp;
timestamp = input(t_timestamp,is8601dt19.);
format timestamp is8601dt.;

do while(1);
  input  
    @'property":'  property :$30. 
    @'oldValue":'  oldValue :8.
    @'newValue":'  newValue :8.
  ;
  output;
  input @;
  if not(index(_infile_,'},')) then leave;
end;
cards;
{  
  "eventsLimited":false,
  "events":[  
    {  
      "_id":"1",
      "userId":"1",
      "timestamp":"2017-05-07T21:37:39.037Z",
      "detailedEvents":[  
        {  
          "eventType":"taskChanged",
          "taskId":"111",
          "changedProperties":[  
            {  
              "property":"totalSecondsSpent",
              "oldValue":0,
              "newValue":3600
            },
            {  
              "property":"totalSecondsEstimate",
              "oldValue":0,
              "newValue":144000
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {  
      "_id":"2",
      "userId":"1",
      "timestamp":"2017-05-07T22:31:30.037Z",
      "detailedEvents":[  
        {  
          "eventType":"taskChanged",
          "taskId":"111",
          "changedProperties":[  
            {  
              "property":"totalSecondsSpent",
              "oldValue":3600,
              "newValue":5400
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
;
run;
```

Comment: You've got my goal right, but unfortunately the JSON is way more complex and huge, so for know i won't hardcode too much. But I like your solution to my problem! And thanks!