# Importing a nested JSON into SAS without LIBNAME engine

Tags: sql, json, testing, sas

I would like to import a JSON with rather intricate structure with SAS. The code we are trying to use leads to the following error message:

> Duplicate records are imported in the work-File in SAS or entire data sets are not imported and thus skipped.
> A Filter restricting the Table structure may be the solution.

So far we are using the option `-- dlm='[]{},:';`. It would also be helpful if we could two filters, e.g. on `S2` and `ETL_SI_SI:`

Here the SAS code:

```
DM "log; clear; ";

%let STARTTIME =%sysfunc(time());
data test;  
DURATION = put(time()-&STARTTIME,hour5.2)||'Hr';    
put DURATION=; run;

%let PathInput = 'R:\...\Arjen\test.json';

PROC Delete data = WORK.ETL_GE_GE; run; 
PROC Delete data = WORK.ETL_SI_SI; run; 
PROC Delete data = WORK.RMP_GE_GE; run; 
PROC Delete data = WORK.RMP_SI_SI; run;
    
data ETL_GE_GE; 
  infile &PathInput. LRECL = 1000000 SCANOVER encoding="utf-8" truncover dsd dlm="}},{"; INPUT @'"SZENARIO_ID":' SZENARIO_ID : best32. @'"GESCHAEFT_FID":' GESCHAEFT_FID : best32. @'"LAND_FID":' LAND_FID : best32. @'"TEILKREDIT_FID":' TEILKREDIT_FID : best32. @'"BOERSENGEHANDELT_TYP_B":' BOERSENGEHANDELT_TYP_B : best32. @'"DURCHLEITGESCHAEFT_TYP_B":' DURCHLEITGESCHAEFT_TYP_B : best32. @'"ENDDATUM_URSPRUENGLICH":' ENDDATUM_URSPRUENGLICH : best32. @'"EWB_CASHFLOW_BASIERT_TYP_B":' EWB_CASHFLOW_BASIERT_TYP_B : best32. @'"FOERDERGESCHAEFT_TYP_B":' FOERDERGESCHAEFT_TYP_B : best32. @'"HALTEKATEGORIE_TYP_S":' KONSORTIALFINANZIERUNG_TYP_B : best32. @'"KONSORTIALFINANZIERUNG_TYP_B":' KONSORTIALFINANZIERUNG_TYP_B : best32. @'"MANDANT_TYP_S":' MANDANT_TYP_S : best32. @'"NACHRANG_TYP_B":' NACHRANG_TYP_B : best32. @'"OBJEKTTYP_EBENE1_TYP_S":' OBJEKTTYP_EBENE1_TYP_S : best32. @'"PROGRAMMKERN_TYP_S":' PROGRAMMKERN_TYP_S : best32. @'"SPEZIALFINANZIERUNG_OP_TYP_B":' SPEZIALFINANZIERUNG_OP_TYP_B : best32. @'"STARTDATUM_URSPRUENGLICH":' STARTDATUM_URSPRUENGLICH : best32. @'"TREUHANDGESCHAEFT_TYP_B":' TREUHANDGESCHAEFT_TYP_B : best32. @'"TYP_TYP_S":' TYP_TYP_S : best32. @'"VERMOEGEN_TYP_S":' VERMOEGEN_TYP_S : best32. @'"WAEHRUNG_TYP_S":' WAEHRUNG_TYP_S : best32. @'"WAEHRUNG_REFINANZIERUNG_TYP_S":' WAEHRUNG_REFINANZIERUNG_TYP_S : best32. @'"KREDITRISIKO_RELEVANT_TYP_B":' KREDITRISIKO_RELEVANT_TYP_B : best32. @'"DURCHLEITBANK_ABGERECHNET_TYP_B":' DURCHLEITBANK_ABGERECHNET_TYP_B : best32.  ; 
run;
    
data ETL_SI_SI; 
  infile &PathInput. LRECL = 1000000 SCANOVER encoding="utf-8" truncover dsd dlm="}},{"; INPUT @'"SICHERHEIT_FID":' SICHERHEIT_FID : best32. @'"SZENARIO_ID":' SZENARIO_ID : best32. @'"ANRECHENBARKEIT_IRBA_TYP_S":' ANRECHENBARKEIT_IRBA_TYP_S : best32. @'"ANRECHENBARKEIT_INTERN_TYP_S":' ANRECHENBARKEIT_INTERN_TYP_S : best32. @'"ANRECHENBARKEIT_KSA_TYP_S":' ANRECHENBARKEIT_KSA_TYP_S : best32. @'"ANRECHNUNGSEBENE_TYP_S":' ANRECHNUNGSEBENE_TYP_S : best32. @'"OBJEKTTYP_EBENE1_TYP_S":' OBJEKTTYP_EBENE1_TYP_S : best32. @'"VERWERTUNGSDAUER":' VERWERTUNGSDAUER : best32.  @'"WAEHRUNG_TYP_S":' WAEHRUNG_TYP_S : best32.  ; 
run;
    
data RMP_GE_GE; 
   infile &PathInput. LRECL = 1000000 SCANOVER encoding="utf-8" truncover dsd dlm="}},{"; INPUT @'"GESCHAEFT_FID":' GESCHAEFT_FID : best32. @'"AVA":' AVA : best32. @'"BAROBLIGO":' BAROBLIGO : best32. @'"BETRAG_HERAUSGELEGT":' BETRAG_HERAUSGELEGT : best32. @'"BEWERTEN_TYP_B":' BEWERTEN_TYP_B : best32. @'"BUCHWERT":' BUCHWERT : best32. @'"ERS":' ERS : best32. @'"EWB":' EWB : best32. @'"PORS":' PORS : best32. @'"POWB":' POWB : best32. @'"RELEVANT_TYP_B":' RELEVANT_TYP_B : best32. @'"RESTLAUFZEIT_OP":' RESTLAUFZEIT_OP : best32. @'"ZUSAGE_OFFEN_OP":' ZUSAGE_OFFEN_OP : best32. @'"ZUSAGEBETRAG":' ZUSAGEBETRAG : best32. @'"ZUSAGEOBLIGO":' ZUSAGEOBLIGO : best32. @'"BUCHWERT_ZUGELIEFERT":' BUCHWERT_ZUGELIEFERT : best32. @'"ZUSAGEOBLIGO_ZUGELIEFERT":' ZUSAGEOBLIGO_ZUGELIEFERT : best32. @'"PORS_ZUGELIEFERT":' PORS_ZUGELIEFERT : best32. @'"POWB_ZUGELIEFERT":' POWB_ZUGELIEFERT : best32. @'"BAROBLIGO_ZUGELIEFERT":' BAROBLIGO_ZUGELIEFERT : best32. @'"BETR_HERAUSGELEGT_ZUGELIEFERT":' BETR_HERAUSGELEGT_ZUGELIEFERT : best32. @'"STARTDATUM":' STARTDATUM : best32. @'"ENDDATUM":' ENDDATUM : best32. @'"BEWERTUNGSTAG":' BEWERTUNGSTAG : best32. /* @'"MINIMAL_BEWERTUNGSTAG_TECHNISCH_TYP_B":' MINIMAL_BEWERTUNGSTAG_TECHNISCH_TYP_B : best32. */ @'"BEBUCHT_TYP_B":' BEBUCHT_TYP_B : best32.; ; 
run;
    
data RMP_SI_SI; 
   infile &PathInput. LRECL = 1000000 SCANOVER encoding="utf-8" truncover dsd dlm="}},{"; INPUT @'"SICHERHEIT_FID":' SICHERHEIT_FID : best32. @'"SZENARIO_ID":' SZENARIO_ID : best32. @'"ANRECHENBARKEIT_IRBA_TYP_S":' ANRECHENBARKEIT_IRBA_TYP_S : best32. @'"ANRECHENBARKEIT_INTERN_TYP_S":' ANRECHENBARKEIT_INTERN_TYP_S : best32. @'"ANRECHENBARKEIT_KSA_TYP_S":' ANRECHENBARKEIT_KSA_TYP_S : best32. @'"ANRECHNUNGSEBENE_TYP_S":' ANRECHNUNGSEBENE_TYP_S : best32. @'"OBJEKTTYP_EBENE1_TYP_S":' OBJEKTTYP_EBENE1_TYP_S : best32.
     @'"VERWERTUNGSDAUER":' VERWERTUNGSDAUER : best32. @'"WAEHRUNG_TYP_S":'
     WAEHRUNG_TYP_S : best32. @'"BEWERTUNGSTAG":' BEWERTUNGSTAG : best32.
     /* @'"MINIMAL_BEWERTUNGSTAG_TECHNISCH_TYP_B":'
     MINIMAL_BEWERTUNGSTAG_TECHNISCH_TYP_B : best32. */  ; 
run;
     
%let DURATION =
%sysfunc(putn(%sysevalf(%sysfunc(time())-&STARTTIME),hour5.2))Hr; 
%put &=DURATION;
```

The `test.json` looks as follows:

```
{
  "metaInformation": {},
  "S2": [
    {
      "ETL_GE_GE": [
        {
          "SZENARIO_ID": 0,
          "GESCHAEFT_FID": 705138,
          "LAND_FID": 205,
          "TEILKREDIT_FID": 2627502,
          "BOERSENGEHANDELT_TYP_B": false,
          "DURCHLEITGESCHAEFT_TYP_B": false,
          "ENDDATUM_URSPRUENGLICH": "2028-03-23",
          "EWB_CASHFLOW_BASIERT_TYP_B": false,
          "FOERDERGESCHAEFT_TYP_B": false,
          "HALTEKATEGORIE_TYP_S": 1,
          "KONSORTIALFINANZIERUNG_TYP_B": false,
          "MANDANT_TYP_S": 2,
          "NACHRANG_TYP_B": false,
          "OBJEKTTYP_EBENE1_TYP_S": 1,
          "PROGRAMMKERN_TYP_S": 5404,
          "SPEZIALFINANZIERUNG_OP_TYP_B": false,
          "STARTDATUM_URSPRUENGLICH": "2013-09-04",
          "TREUHANDGESCHAEFT_TYP_B": false,
          "TYP_TYP_S": 1,
          "VERMOEGEN_TYP_S": 2,
          "WAEHRUNG_TYP_S": 13,
          "WAEHRUNG_REFINANZIERUNG_TYP_S": 13,
          "KREDITRISIKO_RELEVANT_TYP_B": true,
          "DURCHLEITBANK_ABGERECHNET_TYP_B": false
        },
        {
          "SZENARIO_ID": 0,
          "GESCHAEFT_FID": 2278124,
          "LAND_FID": 205,
          "TEILKREDIT_FID": 2892102,
          "BOERSENGEHANDELT_TYP_B": false,
          "DURCHLEITGESCHAEFT_TYP_B": false,
          "ENDDATUM_URSPRUENGLICH": "2033-03-21",
          "EWB_CASHFLOW_BASIERT_TYP_B": false,
          "FOERDERGESCHAEFT_TYP_B": true,
          "HALTEKATEGORIE_TYP_S": 1,
          "KONSORTIALFINANZIERUNG_TYP_B": false,
          "MANDANT_TYP_S": 1,
          "NACHRANG_TYP_B": false,
          "OBJEKTTYP_EBENE1_TYP_S": 1,
          "PROGRAMMKERN_TYP_S": 4322,
          "SPEZIALFINANZIERUNG_OP_TYP_B": false,
          "STARTDATUM_URSPRUENGLICH": "2018-11-15",
          "TREUHANDGESCHAEFT_TYP_B": false,
          "TYP_TYP_S": 1,
          "VERMOEGEN_TYP_S": 2,
          "WAEHRUNG_TYP_S": 201,
          "WAEHRUNG_REFINANZIERUNG_TYP_S": 201,
          "KREDITRISIKO_RELEVANT_TYP_B": true,
          "DURCHLEITBANK_ABGERECHNET_TYP_B": false
        },
        {
          "SZENARIO_ID": 0,
          "GESCHAEFT_FID": 2773809,
          "LAND_FID": 205,
          "TEILKREDIT_FID": 2930505,
          "BOERSENGEHANDELT_TYP_B": false,
          "DURCHLEITGESCHAEFT_TYP_B": false,
          "ENDDATUM_URSPRUENGLICH": "2033-03-21",
          "EWB_CASHFLOW_BASIERT_TYP_B": false,
          "FOERDERGESCHAEFT_TYP_B": true,
          "HALTEKATEGORIE_TYP_S": 1,
          "KONSORTIALFINANZIERUNG_TYP_B": false,
          "MANDANT_TYP_S": 1,
          "NACHRANG_TYP_B": false,
          "OBJEKTTYP_EBENE1_TYP_S": 1,
          "PROGRAMMKERN_TYP_S": 4322,
          "SPEZIALFINANZIERUNG_OP_TYP_B": false,
          "STARTDATUM_URSPRUENGLICH": "2019-03-13",
          "TREUHANDGESCHAEFT_TYP_B": false,
          "TYP_TYP_S": 1,
          "VERMOEGEN_TYP_S": 2,
          "WAEHRUNG_TYP_S": 201,
          "WAEHRUNG_REFINANZIERUNG_TYP_S": 201,
          "KREDITRISIKO_RELEVANT_TYP_B": true,
          "DURCHLEITBANK_ABGERECHNET_TYP_B": false
        },
        {
          "SZENARIO_ID": 0,
          "GESCHAEFT_FID": 2792738,
          "LAND_FID": 205,
          "TEILKREDIT_FID": 2930504,
          "BOERSENGEHANDELT_TYP_B": false,
          "DURCHLEITGESCHAEFT_TYP_B": false,
          "ENDDATUM_URSPRUENGLICH": "2033-09-21",
          "EWB_CASHFLOW_BASIERT_TYP_B": false,
          "FOERDERGESCHAEFT_TYP_B": true,
          "HALTEKATEGORIE_TYP_S": 1,
          "KONSORTIALFINANZIERUNG_TYP_B": false,
          "MANDANT_TYP_S": 1,
          "NACHRANG_TYP_B": false,
          "OBJEKTTYP_EBENE1_TYP_S": 1,
          "PROGRAMMKERN_TYP_S": 4322,
          "SPEZIALFINANZIERUNG_OP_TYP_B": false,
          "STARTDATUM_URSPRUENGLICH": "2019-03-13",
          "TREUHANDGESCHAEFT_TYP_B": false,
          "TYP_TYP_S": 1,
          "VERMOEGEN_TYP_S": 2,
          "WAEHRUNG_TYP_S": 201,
          "WAEHRUNG_REFINANZIERUNG_TYP_S": 201,
          "KREDITRISIKO_RELEVANT_TYP_B": true,
          "DURCHLEITBANK_ABGERECHNET_TYP_B": false
        },
        {
          "SZENARIO_ID": 0,
          "GESCHAEFT_FID": 3138913,
          "LAND_FID": 205,
          "TEILKREDIT_FID": 2627503,
          "BOERSENGEHANDELT_TYP_B": false,
          "DURCHLEITGESCHAEFT_TYP_B": false,
          "ENDDATUM_URSPRUENGLICH": "2028-09-01",
          "EWB_CASHFLOW_BASIERT_TYP_B": false,
          "FOERDERGESCHAEFT_TYP_B": false,
          "HALTEKATEGORIE_TYP_S": 1,
          "KONSORTIALFINANZIERUNG_TYP_B": false,
          "MANDANT_TYP_S": 2,
          "NACHRANG_TYP_B": false,
          "OBJEKTTYP_EBENE1_TYP_S": 1,
          "PROGRAMMKERN_TYP_S": 5404,
          "SPEZIALFINANZIERUNG_OP_TYP_B": false,
          "STARTDATUM_URSPRUENGLICH": "2013-09-04",
          "TREUHANDGESCHAEFT_TYP_B": false,
          "TYP_TYP_S": 1,
          "VERMOEGEN_TYP_S": 2,
          "WAEHRUNG_TYP_S": 13,
          "WAEHRUNG_REFINANZIERUNG_TYP_S": 13,
          "KREDITRISIKO_RELEVANT_TYP_B": true,
          "DURCHLEITBANK_ABGERECHNET_TYP_B": false
        }
      ],
      "ETL_SI_SI": [
        {
          "SICHERHEIT_FID": 33435,
          "SZENARIO_ID": 0,
          "ANRECHENBARKEIT_IRBA_TYP_S": 3,
          "ANRECHENBARKEIT_INTERN_TYP_S": 3,
          "ANRECHENBARKEIT_KSA_TYP_S": 3,
          "ANRECHNUNGSEBENE_TYP_S": 8,
          "OBJEKTTYP_EBENE1_TYP_S": 1,
          "VERWERTUNGSDAUER": 0.5,
          "WAEHRUNG_TYP_S": 201
        },
        {
          "SICHERHEIT_FID": 34244,
          "SZENARIO_ID": 0,
          "ANRECHENBARKEIT_IRBA_TYP_S": 1,
          "ANRECHENBARKEIT_INTERN_TYP_S": 1,
          "ANRECHENBARKEIT_KSA_TYP_S": 1,
          "ANRECHNUNGSEBENE_TYP_S": 3,
          "OBJEKTTYP_EBENE1_TYP_S": 2,
          "VERWERTUNGSDAUER": 0,
          "WAEHRUNG_TYP_S": 201
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "S3": [
    {
      "RMP_GE_GE": [
        {
          "GESCHAEFT_FID": 705138,
          "AVA": "NaN",
          "BAROBLIGO": 755940.4336239336,
          "BETRAG_HERAUSGELEGT": 0,
          "BEWERTEN_TYP_B": true,
          "BUCHWERT": 757208.784969132,
          "ERS": "NaN",
          "EWB": "NaN",
          "PORS": 114.3961003307755,
          "POWB": 768.9539726541052,
          "RELEVANT_TYP_B": true,
          "RESTLAUFZEIT_OP": 3555,
          "ZUSAGE_OFFEN_OP": 2035224.2550855055,
          "ZUSAGEBETRAG": 2791164.6887094392,
          "ZUSAGEOBLIGO": 2791164.6887094392,
          "BUCHWERT_ZUGELIEFERT": 757208.784969132,
          "ZUSAGEOBLIGO_ZUGELIEFERT": 2791164.6887094392,
          "PORS_ZUGELIEFERT": 114.3961003307755,
          "POWB_ZUGELIEFERT": 768.9539726541052,
          "BAROBLIGO_ZUGELIEFERT": 755940.4336239336,
          "BETR_HERAUSGELEGT_ZUGELIEFERT": 0,
          "STARTDATUM": "2013-09-04",
          "ENDDATUM": "2028-03-23",
          "BEWERTUNGSTAG": "2018-06-29",
          "MINIMAL_BEWERTUNGSTAG_TECHNISCH_TYP_B": true,
          "BEBUCHT_TYP_B": true
        },
        {
          "GESCHAEFT_FID": 2773809,
          "AMORTISIERUNGEN": -1645.79,
          "AVA": "NaN",
          "BAROBLIGO": 0,
          "BETRAG_HERAUSGELEGT": 0,
          "BEWERTEN_TYP_B": true,
          "BUCHWERT": -1459.69,
          "ERS": "NaN",
          "EWB": "NaN",
          "PORS": 165.17,
          "POWB": "NaN",
          "RELEVANT_TYP_B": true,
          "RESTLAUFZEIT_OP": 5379,
          "ZUSAGE_OFFEN_OP": 507613.25,
          "ZUSAGEBETRAG": 507613.25,
          "ZUSAGEOBLIGO": 507613.25,
          "BUCHWERT_ZUGELIEFERT": -1459.69,
          "ZUSAGEOBLIGO_ZUGELIEFERT": 507613.25,
          "PORS_ZUGELIEFERT": 165.17,
          "BAROBLIGO_ZUGELIEFERT": 0,
          "BETR_HERAUSGELEGT_ZUGELIEFERT": 0,
          "STARTDATUM": "2019-03-13",
          "ENDDATUM": "2033-03-21",
          "BEWERTUNGSTAG": "2018-06-29",
          "MINIMAL_BEWERTUNGSTAG_TECHNISCH_TYP_B": true,
          "BEBUCHT_TYP_B": false
        },
        {
          "GESCHAEFT_FID": 299792458,
          "AVA": "NaN",
          "BAROBLIGO": 725292.4162682628,
          "BETRAG_HERAUSGELEGT": 0,
          "BEWERTEN_TYP_B": true,
          "BUCHWERT": 727229.2501975278,
          "ERS": "NaN",
          "EWB": "NaN",
          "PORS": 145.38989996384234,
          "POWB": 740.2086430168869,
          "RELEVANT_TYP_B": true,
          "RESTLAUFZEIT_OP": 3717,
          "ZUSAGE_OFFEN_OP": 2439619.9335770626,
          "ZUSAGEBETRAG": 3164912.349845325,
          "ZUSAGEOBLIGO": 3164912.349845325,
          "BUCHWERT_ZUGELIEFERT": 727229.2501975278,
          "ZUSAGEOBLIGO_ZUGELIEFERT": 3164912.349845325,
          "PORS_ZUGELIEFERT": 145.38989996384234,
          "POWB_ZUGELIEFERT": 740.2086430168869,
          "BAROBLIGO_ZUGELIEFERT": 725292.4162682628,
          "BETR_HERAUSGELEGT_ZUGELIEFERT": 0,
          "STARTDATUM": "2013-09-04",
          "ENDDATUM": "2028-09-01",
          "BEWERTUNGSTAG": "2018-06-29",
          "MINIMAL_BEWERTUNGSTAG_TECHNISCH_TYP_B": true,
          "BEBUCHT_TYP_B": true
        }
      ],
      "RMP_SI_SI": [
        {
          "SICHERHEIT_FID": 33435,
          "SZENARIO_ID": 0,
          "ANRECHENBARKEIT_IRBA_TYP_S": 3,
          "ANRECHENBARKEIT_INTERN_TYP_S": 3,
          "ANRECHENBARKEIT_KSA_TYP_S": 3,
          "ANRECHNUNGSEBENE_TYP_S": 8,
          "OBJEKTTYP_EBENE1_TYP_S": 1,
          "VERWERTUNGSDAUER": 0.5,
          "WAEHRUNG_TYP_S": 201,
          "BEWERTUNGSTAG": "2018-06-29",
          "MINIMAL_BEWERTUNGSTAG_TECHNISCH_TYP_B": true
        },
        {
          "SICHERHEIT_FID": 33435,
          "SZENARIO_ID": 0,
          "ANRECHENBARKEIT_IRBA_TYP_S": 3,
          "ANRECHENBARKEIT_INTERN_TYP_S": 3,
          "ANRECHENBARKEIT_KSA_TYP_S": 3,
          "ANRECHNUNGSEBENE_TYP_S": 8,
          "OBJEKTTYP_EBENE1_TYP_S": 1,
          "VERWERTUNGSDAUER": 0.5,
          "WAEHRUNG_TYP_S": 201,
          "BEWERTUNGSTAG": "2018-06-30",
          "MINIMAL_BEWERTUNGSTAG_TECHNISCH_TYP_B": false
        },
        {
          "SICHERHEIT_FID": 34244,
          "SZENARIO_ID": 0,
          "ANRECHENBARKEIT_IRBA_TYP_S": 1,
          "ANRECHENBARKEIT_INTERN_TYP_S": 1,
          "ANRECHENBARKEIT_KSA_TYP_S": 1,
          "ANRECHNUNGSEBENE_TYP_S": 3,
          "OBJEKTTYP_EBENE1_TYP_S": 2,
          "VERWERTUNGSDAUER": 0,
          "WAEHRUNG_TYP_S": 201,
          "BEWERTUNGSTAG": "2018-06-29",
          "MINIMAL_BEWERTUNGSTAG_TECHNISCH_TYP_B": true
        },
        {
          "SICHERHEIT_FID": 34244,
          "SZENARIO_ID": 0,
          "ANRECHENBARKEIT_IRBA_TYP_S": 1,
          "ANRECHENBARKEIT_INTERN_TYP_S": 1,
          "ANRECHENBARKEIT_KSA_TYP_S": 1,
          "ANRECHNUNGSEBENE_TYP_S": 3,
          "OBJEKTTYP_EBENE1_TYP_S": 2,
          "VERWERTUNGSDAUER": 0,
          "WAEHRUNG_TYP_S": 201,
          "BEWERTUNGSTAG": "2018-06-30",
          "MINIMAL_BEWERTUNGSTAG_TECHNISCH_TYP_B": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you try just letting SAS try to parse the JSON file with the JSON libname engine instead of trying to read it with a data step? You could use the AUTOMAP feature or build your own mapping file for it to use.

Comment: The Json libname engine is unfortunately not supported in the SAS version that we use. Therefore, I was compelled to use this script as a manual workaround. I do not know, how to change the filter logic properly. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It's pronounced 'Jason' but JSON stands for Java Script Object Notation not Jason.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I could now refer to the [guidelines how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also lecture you on [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but I will instead just try to improve your question. Please let me know, whether it makes sense.

Comment: Another observation while editin: The JSON you posted initially did not validate because of missing quote-symbols for some of their keys which I fixed, e.g. `"metaInformation"``. You might want to check that upstream, i.e. from where-ever the input-JSONs are provided.

Comment: Related posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47076473/reading-json-file-without-the-sas-json-libname-engine and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36444012/parse-json-object-in-sas-macro-part-2-using-output-function-to-handle-nested

Answer (score 0):

Use `PowerShell`  cmdlet `ConvertFrom-Json` to parse the `json` file and extract the relevant field values from the desired json path.

A filename pipe that executes a powershell command will deliver one name value row per object property and separated the owning objects with a blank line.  The name values can be grouped and later transposed.  Data cleaning and transformation to appropriate SAS data types and formats would be coded during or soon after.

For example, knowing path to ETL_GE_GE data array elements is /S2/ETL_GE_GE you would specify `.S2.ETL_GE_GE` in the filename pipe command.

```
* single quoted json filename for use in filename statement;
%let sq_path = %sysfunc(quote(%sysfunc(pathname(JSON)),%str(%')));

filename PSPARSE pipe 
"powershell -command ""(Get-Content &sq_path | ConvertFrom-Json).S2.ETL_GE_GE""";
```

Example:

Create local json file for sample code

```
filename json 'c:\temp\sample.json';

data _null_;
  file json;
  input; 
  put _infile_;
datalines4;
{ metaInformation: {}, "S2": [{        ETL_GE_GE:
 [{"SZENARIO_ID":0,"GESCHAEFT_FID":705138,"LAND_FID":205,"TEILKREDIT_FID":2627502,"BOERSENGEHANDELT_TYP_B":false,"DURCHLEITGESCHAEFT_TYP_B":false,"ENDDATUM_URSPRUENGLICH":"2028-03-23","EWB_CASHFLOW_BASIERT_TYP_B":false,"FOERDERGESCHAEFT_TYP_B":false,"HALTEKATEGORIE_TYP_S":1,"KONSORTIALFINANZIERUNG_TYP_B":false,"MANDANT_TYP_S":2,"NACHRANG_TYP_B":false,"OBJEKTTYP_EBENE1_TYP_S":1,"PROGRAMMKERN_TYP_S":5404,"SPEZIALFINANZIERUNG_OP_TYP_B":false,"STARTDATUM_URSPRUENGLICH":"2013-09-04","TREUHANDGESCHAEFT_TYP_B":false,"TYP_TYP_S":1,"VERMOEGEN_TYP_S":2,"WAEHRUNG_TYP_S":13,"WAEHRUNG_REFINANZIERUNG_TYP_S":13,"KREDITRISIKO_RELEVANT_TYP_B":true,"DURCHLEITBANK_ABGERECHNET_TYP_B":false},
                    {"SZENARIO_ID":0,"GESCHAEFT_FID":2278124,"LAND_FID":205,"TEILKREDIT_FID":2892102,"BOERSENGEHANDELT_TYP_B":false,"DURCHLEITGESCHAEFT_TYP_B":false,"ENDDATUM_URSPRUENGLICH":"2033-03-21","EWB_CASHFLOW_BASIERT_TYP_B":false,"FOERDERGESCHAEFT_TYP_B":true,"HALTEKATEGORIE_TYP_S":1,"KONSORTIALFINANZIERUNG_TYP_B":false,"MANDANT_TYP_S":1,"NACHRANG_TYP_B":false,"OBJEKTTYP_EBENE1_TYP_S":1,"PROGRAMMKERN_TYP_S":4322,"SPEZIALFINANZIERUNG_OP_TYP_B":false,"STARTDATUM_URSPRUENGLICH":"2018-11-15","TREUHANDGESCHAEFT_TYP_B":false,"TYP_TYP_S":1,"VERMOEGEN_TYP_S":2,"WAEHRUNG_TYP_S":201,"WAEHRUNG_REFINANZIERUNG_TYP_S":201,"KREDITRISIKO_RELEVANT_TYP_B":true,"DURCHLEITBANK_ABGERECHNET_TYP_B":false},
                    {"SZENARIO_ID":0,"GESCHAEFT_FID":2773809,"LAND_FID":205,"TEILKREDIT_FID":2930505,"BOERSENGEHANDELT_TYP_B":false,"DURCHLEITGESCHAEFT_TYP_B":false,"ENDDATUM_URSPRUENGLICH":"2033-03-21","EWB_CASHFLOW_BASIERT_TYP_B":false,"FOERDERGESCHAEFT_TYP_B":true,"HALTEKATEGORIE_TYP_S":1,"KONSORTIALFINANZIERUNG_TYP_B":false,"MANDANT_TYP_S":1,"NACHRANG_TYP_B":false,"OBJEKTTYP_EBENE1_TYP_S":1,"PROGRAMMKERN_TYP_S":4322,"SPEZIALFINANZIERUNG_OP_TYP_B":false,"STARTDATUM_URSPRUENGLICH":"2019-03-13","TREUHANDGESCHAEFT_TYP_B":false,"TYP_TYP_S":1,"VERMOEGEN_TYP_S":2,"WAEHRUNG_TYP_S":201,"WAEHRUNG_REFINANZIERUNG_TYP_S":201,"KREDITRISIKO_RELEVANT_TYP_B":true,"DURCHLEITBANK_ABGERECHNET_TYP_B":false},
                    {"SZENARIO_ID":0,"GESCHAEFT_FID":2792738,"LAND_FID":205,"TEILKREDIT_FID":2930504,"BOERSENGEHANDELT_TYP_B":false,"DURCHLEITGESCHAEFT_TYP_B":false,"ENDDATUM_URSPRUENGLICH":"2033-09-21","EWB_CASHFLOW_BASIERT_TYP_B":false,"FOERDERGESCHAEFT_TYP_B":true,"HALTEKATEGORIE_TYP_S":1,"KONSORTIALFINANZIERUNG_TYP_B":false,"MANDANT_TYP_S":1,"NACHRANG_TYP_B":false,"OBJEKTTYP_EBENE1_TYP_S":1,"PROGRAMMKERN_TYP_S":4322,"SPEZIALFINANZIERUNG_OP_TYP_B":false,"STARTDATUM_URSPRUENGLICH":"2019-03-13","TREUHANDGESCHAEFT_TYP_B":false,"TYP_TYP_S":1,"VERMOEGEN_TYP_S":2,"WAEHRUNG_TYP_S":201,"WAEHRUNG_REFINANZIERUNG_TYP_S":201,"KREDITRISIKO_RELEVANT_TYP_B":true,"DURCHLEITBANK_ABGERECHNET_TYP_B":false},
                    {"SZENARIO_ID":0,"GESCHAEFT_FID":3138913,"LAND_FID":205,"TEILKREDIT_FID":2627503,"BOERSENGEHANDELT_TYP_B":false,"DURCHLEITGESCHAEFT_TYP_B":false,"ENDDATUM_URSPRUENGLICH":"2028-09-01","EWB_CASHFLOW_BASIERT_TYP_B":false,"FOERDERGESCHAEFT_TYP_B":false,"HALTEKATEGORIE_TYP_S":1,"KONSORTIALFINANZIERUNG_TYP_B":false,"MANDANT_TYP_S":2,"NACHRANG_TYP_B":false,"OBJEKTTYP_EBENE1_TYP_S":1,"PROGRAMMKERN_TYP_S":5404,"SPEZIALFINANZIERUNG_OP_TYP_B":false,"STARTDATUM_URSPRUENGLICH":"2013-09-04","TREUHANDGESCHAEFT_TYP_B":false,"TYP_TYP_S":1,"VERMOEGEN_TYP_S":2,"WAEHRUNG_TYP_S":13,"WAEHRUNG_REFINANZIERUNG_TYP_S":13,"KREDITRISIKO_RELEVANT_TYP_B":true,"DURCHLEITBANK_ABGERECHNET_TYP_B":false}],
        ETL_SI_SI:
 [{"SICHERHEIT_FID":33435,"SZENARIO_ID":0,"ANRECHENBARKEIT_IRBA_TYP_S":3,"ANRECHENBARKEIT_INTERN_TYP_S":3,"ANRECHENBARKEIT_KSA_TYP_S":3,"ANRECHNUNGSEBENE_TYP_S":8,"OBJEKTTYP_EBENE1_TYP_S":1,"VERWERTUNGSDAUER":0.5,"WAEHRUNG_TYP_S":201},
                    {"SICHERHEIT_FID":34244,"SZENARIO_ID":0,"ANRECHENBARKEIT_IRBA_TYP_S":1,"ANRECHENBARKEIT_INTERN_TYP_S":1,"ANRECHENBARKEIT_KSA_TYP_S":1,"ANRECHNUNGSEBENE_TYP_S":3,"OBJEKTTYP_EBENE1_TYP_S":2,"VERWERTUNGSDAUER":0.0,"WAEHRUNG_TYP_S":201}]
    }], "S3": [{        RMP_GE_GE:
 [{"GESCHAEFT_FID":705138,"AVA":"NaN","BAROBLIGO":755940.4336239336,"BETRAG_HERAUSGELEGT":0.0,"BEWERTEN_TYP_B":true,"BUCHWERT":757208.784969132,"ERS":"NaN","EWB":"NaN","PORS":114.3961003307755,"POWB":768.9539726541052,"RELEVANT_TYP_B":true,"RESTLAUFZEIT_OP":3555,"ZUSAGE_OFFEN_OP":2035224.2550855055,"ZUSAGEBETRAG":2791164.6887094392,"ZUSAGEOBLIGO":2791164.6887094392,"BUCHWERT_ZUGELIEFERT":757208.784969132,"ZUSAGEOBLIGO_ZUGELIEFERT":2791164.6887094392,"PORS_ZUGELIEFERT":114.3961003307755,"POWB_ZUGELIEFERT":768.9539726541052,"BAROBLIGO_ZUGELIEFERT":755940.4336239336,"BETR_HERAUSGELEGT_ZUGELIEFERT":0.0,"STARTDATUM":"2013-09-04","ENDDATUM":"2028-03-23","BEWERTUNGSTAG":"2018-06-29","MINIMAL_BEWERTUNGSTAG_TECHNISCH_TYP_B":true,"BEBUCHT_TYP_B":true},
                    {"GESCHAEFT_FID":2278124,"AMORTISIERUNGEN":-92544.22,"AVA":"NaN","BAROBLIGO":7280000.0,"BETRAG_HERAUSGELEGT":0.0,"BEWERTEN_TYP_B":true,"BUCHWERT":7196903.52,"ERS":"NaN","EWB":"NaN","PORS":637.98,"POWB":7213.72,"RELEVANT_TYP_B":true,"RESTLAUFZEIT_OP":5379,"ZUSAGE_OFFEN_OP":7280000.0,"ZUSAGEBETRAG":1.456E7,"ZUSAGEOBLIGO":1.456E7,"BUCHWERT_ZUGELIEFERT":7196903.52,"ZUSAGEOBLIGO_ZUGELIEFERT":1.456E7,"PORS_ZUGELIEFERT":637.98,"POWB_ZUGELIEFERT":7213.72,"BAROBLIGO_ZUGELIEFERT":7280000.0,"BETR_HERAUSGELEGT_ZUGELIEFERT":0.0,"STARTDATUM":"2018-11-15","ENDDATUM":"2033-03-21","BEWERTUNGSTAG":"2018-06-29","MINIMAL_BEWERTUNGSTAG_TECHNISCH_TYP_B":true,"BEBUCHT_TYP_B":true},
                    {"GESCHAEFT_FID":2773809,"AMORTISIERUNGEN":-1645.79,"AVA":"NaN","BAROBLIGO":0.0,"BETRAG_HERAUSGELEGT":0.0,"BEWERTEN_TYP_B":true,"BUCHWERT":-1459.69,"ERS":"NaN","EWB":"NaN","PORS":165.17,"POWB":"NaN","RELEVANT_TYP_B":true,"RESTLAUFZEIT_OP":5379,"ZUSAGE_OFFEN_OP":507613.25,"ZUSAGEBETRAG":507613.25,"ZUSAGEOBLIGO":507613.25,"BUCHWERT_ZUGELIEFERT":-1459.69,"ZUSAGEOBLIGO_ZUGELIEFERT":507613.25,"PORS_ZUGELIEFERT":165.17,"BAROBLIGO_ZUGELIEFERT":0.0,"BETR_HERAUSGELEGT_ZUGELIEFERT":0.0,"STARTDATUM":"2019-03-13","ENDDATUM":"2033-03-21","BEWERTUNGSTAG":"2018-06-29","MINIMAL_BEWERTUNGSTAG_TECHNISCH_TYP_B":true,"BEBUCHT_TYP_B":false},
                    {"GESCHAEFT_FID":2792738,"AMORTISIERUNGEN":-25833.24,"AVA":"NaN","BAROBLIGO":0.0,"BETRAG_HERAUSGELEGT":0.0,"BEWERTEN_TYP_B":true,"BUCHWERT":-22914.58,"ERS":"NaN","EWB":"NaN","PORS":2590.1,"POWB":"NaN","RELEVANT_TYP_B":true,"RESTLAUFZEIT_OP":5563,"ZUSAGE_OFFEN_OP":7960000.0,"ZUSAGEBETRAG":7960000.0,"ZUSAGEOBLIGO":7960000.0,"BUCHWERT_ZUGELIEFERT":-22914.58,"ZUSAGEOBLIGO_ZUGELIEFERT":7960000.0,"PORS_ZUGELIEFERT":2590.1,"BAROBLIGO_ZUGELIEFERT":0.0,"BETR_HERAUSGELEGT_ZUGELIEFERT":0.0,"STARTDATUM":"2019-03-13","ENDDATUM":"2033-09-21","BEWERTUNGSTAG":"2018-06-29","MINIMAL_BEWERTUNGSTAG_TECHNISCH_TYP_B":true,"BEBUCHT_TYP_B":false},
                    {"GESCHAEFT_FID":3138913,"AVA":"NaN","BAROBLIGO":725292.4162682628,"BETRAG_HERAUSGELEGT":0.0,"BEWERTEN_TYP_B":true,"BUCHWERT":727229.2501975278,"ERS":"NaN","EWB":"NaN","PORS":145.38989996384234,"POWB":740.2086430168869,"RELEVANT_TYP_B":true,"RESTLAUFZEIT_OP":3717,"ZUSAGE_OFFEN_OP":2439619.9335770626,"ZUSAGEBETRAG":3164912.349845325,"ZUSAGEOBLIGO":3164912.349845325,"BUCHWERT_ZUGELIEFERT":727229.2501975278,"ZUSAGEOBLIGO_ZUGELIEFERT":3164912.349845325,"PORS_ZUGELIEFERT":145.38989996384234,"POWB_ZUGELIEFERT":740.2086430168869,"BAROBLIGO_ZUGELIEFERT":725292.4162682628,"BETR_HERAUSGELEGT_ZUGELIEFERT":0.0,"STARTDATUM":"2013-09-04","ENDDATUM":"2028-09-01","BEWERTUNGSTAG":"2018-06-29","MINIMAL_BEWERTUNGSTAG_TECHNISCH_TYP_B":true,"BEBUCHT_TYP_B":true}],
        RMP_SI_SI:
 [{"SICHERHEIT_FID":33435,"SZENARIO_ID":0,"ANRECHENBARKEIT_IRBA_TYP_S":3,"ANRECHENBARKEIT_INTERN_TYP_S":3,"ANRECHENBARKEIT_KSA_TYP_S":3,"ANRECHNUNGSEBENE_TYP_S":8,"OBJEKTTYP_EBENE1_TYP_S":1,"VERWERTUNGSDAUER":0.5,"WAEHRUNG_TYP_S":201,"BEWERTUNGSTAG":"2018-06-29","MINIMAL_BEWERTUNGSTAG_TECHNISCH_TYP_B":true},
                    {"SICHERHEIT_FID":33435,"SZENARIO_ID":0,"ANRECHENBARKEIT_IRBA_TYP_S":3,"ANRECHENBARKEIT_INTERN_TYP_S":3,"ANRECHENBARKEIT_KSA_TYP_S":3,"ANRECHNUNGSEBENE_TYP_S":8,"OBJEKTTYP_EBENE1_TYP_S":1,"VERWERTUNGSDAUER":0.5,"WAEHRUNG_TYP_S":201,"BEWERTUNGSTAG":"2018-06-30","MINIMAL_BEWERTUNGSTAG_TECHNISCH_TYP_B":false},
                    {"SICHERHEIT_FID":34244,"SZENARIO_ID":0,"ANRECHENBARKEIT_IRBA_TYP_S":1,"ANRECHENBARKEIT_INTERN_TYP_S":1,"ANRECHENBARKEIT_KSA_TYP_S":1,"ANRECHNUNGSEBENE_TYP_S":3,"OBJEKTTYP_EBENE1_TYP_S":2,"VERWERTUNGSDAUER":0.0,"WAEHRUNG_TYP_S":201,"BEWERTUNGSTAG":"2018-06-29","MINIMAL_BEWERTUNGSTAG_TECHNISCH_TYP_B":true},
                    {"SICHERHEIT_FID":34244,"SZENARIO_ID":0,"ANRECHENBARKEIT_IRBA_TYP_S":1,"ANRECHENBARKEIT_INTERN_TYP_S":1,"ANRECHENBARKEIT_KSA_TYP_S":1,"ANRECHNUNGSEBENE_TYP_S":3,"OBJEKTTYP_EBENE1_TYP_S":2,"VERWERTUNGSDAUER":0.0,"WAEHRUNG_TYP_S":201,"BEWERTUNGSTAG":"2018-06-30","MINIMAL_BEWERTUNGSTAG_TECHNISCH_TYP_B":false}]
    }] }
;;;;
```

Read parsed JSON file and transpose into wide structured SAS data set.

```
* Replace path with your actual path;
* filename JSON '<path to downloaded json file>';

* single quoted json filename for use in filename statement;
%let sq_path = %sysfunc(quote(%sysfunc(pathname(JSON)),%str(%')));

filename PSPARSE pipe 
"powershell -command ""(Get-Content &sq_path | ConvertFrom-Json).S2.ETL_GE_GE""";

data ETL_GE_GE_name_value_pairs;
  infile PSPARSE delimiter=':' missover;
  length longname value $100;
  retain row 1;
  input longname value;
  if missing(longname) then row+1;
  if length(longname) > 32 then put 'WARNING: ' longname=;
run;  

proc transpose data=ETL_GE_GE_name_value_pairs out=ETL_GE_GE (drop=row _name_);
  where not missing(longname);
  by row;
  var value;
  id longname;
run;

* ... more code for further data transformation ...;
```

Repeat the code for `S2.ETL_SI_SI`, `S3.RMP_GE_GE`, and `S3.RMP_SI_SI`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the helpful hints and comments.

Works fine. I am working on transposing the data properly to obtain a table structure.

Attribute 1, Attribute 2, ...., Attribute n

Outcome1-A, Outcome2-A, ....,  Outcome n-A
.....

[image]

Kind Regards and Stay healthy,
Kingsley